# In ng-youtube-embed tag how to use ng-repeat for dynamic videos?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

i need to display youtube videos on my page dynamicall in  tag but  expression and ng-repeat is not working.

Here is my code

```
<ng-youtube-embed ng-repeat= data in videos url="{{data}}"  class="galleryItem" 
                            width="100%" ng-click="vm.setImage( image.thumb )">
                    </ng-youtube-embed>

Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngRepeat/iexp?p0=data
N/<@http://localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:6:412
Je</<.compile@http://localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:301:120
oa@http://localhost:3000/js/angular.min.js:71:36
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing some `""` around `data in videos`

Comment: No , see <ng-youtube-embed url="'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jzk0RaRfNvc'"  class="galleryItem" 
                            width="100%" ng-click="vm.setImage( image.thumb )">
                </ng-youtube-embed>

Answer (score 0):

You are using it incorrectly.

Try this -

```
<div ng-repeat="data in videos" class="galleryItem" ng-click="vm.setImage(image.thumb)">
    <ng-youtube-embed 
        url="data"
        width="100%">
    </ng-youtube-embed>
</div>
```